# why the value of html text field get change when it has comma?

Tags: javascript, html, events, getelementbyid, entities

i have the following function to calculate cpm

function CalCPM()
{

```
    var nv = document.getElementById('txtviews').value;
    var nc = document.getElementById('txtcost').value;
    var result =parseFloat(nc) / parseFloat(nv)/1000;
    if(!isNaN(result))
       {
        document.getElementById('cpm').value = result.toFixed(4); 
       }
```

}

it work fine expect when you put comma in the number, means
if you put in 
txtviews 1000000 
and in txtcost 3000 you get a correct result that is 3.000

However if you use commas in any of the numbers then the problem starts, like

if you put in 
txtviews 1,000,000 
and in txtcost 3,000

then the result will be 0.000003

which is not a correct value,  any idea why??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The number format used by `parseFloat` doesn't recognise the comma as a thousands separator. Everything after it is ignored.

`parseFloat("1,000,000")` is treated in the same was as `parseFloat("1P000P000");`, i.e. as `1`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

> If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters.

Answer (score 0):

This should help to get rid of commas and convert your value to number

```
nc = parseFloat(nc.replace(/,/g, '')); //get rid of commas
nv = parseFloat(nv.replace(/,/g, ''));
var result = nc / nv/1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reg-ex this will be the solution :

```
function CalCPM()
{
  var nv = (document.getElementById('txtviews').value).replace(/,/g,'');
  var nc = (document.getElementById('txtcost').value).replace(/,/g,'');
  var result =parseFloat(nc) / parseFloat(nv)/1000;
  if(!isNaN(result))
  {
  document.getElementById('cpm').value = Number(result).toFixed(4); 
  }
}
```